# How I get data like 0 to 50 and 51 to 100 in laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to get data from database with range like 0 to 50 and 51 to 100, this is possible? if possible please talk me how to do that.

```
$users = User::all();
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not able to get clearly what do you want. But I have provided some examples below that might work for you.

```
$users = DB::table('users')
           ->whereBetween('id', [1, 50])
           ->get();
```

Also try `skip` and `take`.
You may use the skip and take methods to limit the number of results returned from the query or to skip a given number of results in the query:

```
$users = DB::table('users')->skip(50)->take(50)->get();
```

Alternatively, you may use the limit and offset methods. These methods are functionally equivalent to the take and skip methods, respectively:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
                ->offset(50)
                ->limit(50)
                ->get();
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of options available to you. If you're looking to obtain a working data set of `x` results at a time and not concerned about the `id` of the results, then one of the following might be of use:

- [Pagination](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/pagination#paginating-eloquent-results)
- [Chunking results](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#chunking-results)

Both of the above will allow you to define the size/number of records returned for your data set.

If you're looking to return records between specific `id` values, then you'll want to use something like [`whereBetween`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-wherebetween) on your database queries. The `whereBetween` clause can be used in conjunction with the pagination and chunking.